# How migrate physical postgres database data to postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, boot2docker

I have postgres database with stored data. 
Now i want to change my application to run in a container and reading from earlier stored data in postgres database.
But how to create volume with already stored data?
A don't want to lose any data. How to achieve it?

Comment: Same as migrating with another physical postgres database. Nothing specific about docker here. You should post another question without mention of docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use `pg_dump` https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/9.6/app-pgdump

You need to dump a database to file at first

```
pg_dump mydb > db.sql
```

After your container is running you need to restore this data from file as

```
psql -d newdb -f db.sql
```